# Time-Based Workflow Actions and Workflow Rule Criteria Question

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have a workflow rule for a task record with evaluation criteria of *Evaluate the rule when a record is created and any time  its edited to subsequently meet criteria*.

The process is:

1. When a task record is created, the task owner will get email notification
2. Time-based actions for 1 hour, 2 hours, 4 days, and 7 days are created in the time-based queue.

The workflow can either fire on this condition:

1. Status field =  'Not Started'
2. MQP_Types__c field is not null
3. Task Owner First Name != 'Unassigned'

Or this 2nd condition:

1. Status field =  'Not Started'
2. MQP_Types__c field is not null
3. Task Owner First Name != 'Unassigned'
4. Reassignments__c field's last character is a hyphen ('-')
5. Task Owner First Name != 'Unassigned'
6. CreatedDate <> LastModifiedDate

Thus this means that the workflow rule should only fire when a task is created or when the task has been modified where the Reassignments__c field's last character is a '-' due to some  automation tool that updates this field.

Questions:

1. Will Time-based Actions still load into the time-based queue after a all the actions have fired off their emails (leaving the queue empty) and the task has been updated using the second condition?
2. If the task is created with time-based actions why do the 1 hour and 2 hours time-based workflow actions show "LastModifiedDate"  while the 4 Day and 7 Day time-based workflow actions show "Created Date" on the Workflow Actions Edit Page"?
3. Also why wouldn't the 4-Day and 7-Day workflow actions always show up in the time-based queue along with the 1 hour and 2 hour actions?

Here are my screen scrapes to show what I mean. Thanks

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I believe I have discovered the answer.
Since we are creating time-based workflow email alert actions whenever a task is created and also whenever a sales leader reassign the task to a sales person, I will need 2 workflows.

1. The first workflow will be used to create the time-base email alerts for the task's
   first owner and will add an offset of 4,7,10, and 14 days off of the created date.
2. The second workflow rule will include within the criteria a value in the custom
   Reassignments__c field that readily identifies the owner as the sales person who had
   the task reassigned to them.
3. It will fire new time-based email alerts after the 14th of the first task owner . So
   it should have its own list of 4,7,10, and 14 days for this sales person.
4. The Sales Leader - who is the intermediate owner between the first owner and the salesperson should not get any time-based email alerts added into the time-based queue for them.